# ASP.net file upload from a non server - issue with Server.MapPath?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to upload a file in asp.net using the following code

```
Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ClientFileName) 
MyFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImportedFiles/" + FileName))
```

if the file being uploaded (say book1.xls) resides on the machine that is also the server all works perfectly, but if the file resides on a Pc that is not the server it fails on the second line.  I think the problem is that Server.MapPath seems to refer to the non server PC when it is uploaded from there.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImportedFiles/")+FileName

Comment: Please advise on how you are getting `ClientFileName`

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to "grab" a file to "upload" in CodeBehind? Or do you let users select and upload files through the browser? 

You cannot "take" files from client machines.

Comment: Hi Jon The user selects a file from a dialogue box and the code is Dim strClientFileName As String = MyFile.PostedFile.FileName

Comment: Hi Alexander Yes I am trying to grab a file to upload and save in a folder in the project - what do you mean you cant take files from Clients machines - I have done that when my machine is both client and server - I think the problem is saving it to the project folder on the server

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly getting file name. You should use below code

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
```

Of course change control name to your own.

Please See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Comment: @Garath... hope you don't mind me adding a link to the MSDN on this

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Path.GetFileName is just a static/shared function that returns the file name for a given path. Presumably in OP's question, ClientFileName is either the full path to the uploaded file or even just the file name itself. All that is being used for is to have a name to save the file as in the second line. Could you explain further?

Comment: Thanks for that - I think it is getting the correct name (it is getting Book1.xls - I think it is the save Asline thats the issue Dave

Comment: What exactly error you have? And did you check path were you are trying to save?

Comment: file does not exist - I think the problem is that I am trying to save it to a server path but it is trying to save it to the local PC.

Comment: Does asp.net has rights to write your upload folder? Server.Map will does not know anything about client side. What exactly error you have?

Comment: The error is file does not exist - can you tell me what Server.Map path refers to?

Comment: Can you add stacktrace?